# ML lemma question

Tags: complex-analysis

Denote by $\Gamma_R$ the semicircle $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|=R,  0\leq \arg(z) \leq \pi\}$ traversed in the counter clockwise direction. Using the $ML$ Lemma, show that $$|\int \limits_{\Gamma_R} \frac{1}{z^4+1} dz | \rightarrow 0$$ as $R\rightarrow \infty$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma

The length $L$ would be $2R$ right? And the maximum of the $f(z)$ would be $f(R)$ wouldn't it because we have the condition of $|z|=R$ right? I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R > 0$ such that $R^4 > 2$. On $\Gamma_R$, $$\left|\frac{1}{z^4 + 1}\right| = \frac{1}{|z^4 + 1|} \le \frac{1}{R^4 - 1} \le \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}R^4} = \frac{2}{R^4}$$

The arclength of $\Gamma_R$ is $\pi R$, so by the ML-inequality,

$$\int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{dz}{z^4 + 1} = O\left( \frac{1}{R^3}\right)$$

Since $\frac{1}{R^3} \to 0$ as $R\to \infty$, the result follows.

Comment: How did you find out that the length is piR? isn't the $\Gamma$ just the top quadrants of a circle centred at origin which has radius R? What exactly is the length, is it the maximum horizontal length?

Comment: So in this lemma, when they talk about L, they are talking about the perimeter?

Comment: @snowman yes, that's another way of putting it.

Comment: thanks. it says |z|=R and not |z|<R so doesn't that mean the only value that f(z) can be is f(R)? so we cant really write f(z)$\leq$f(R) since it can only equal that...

Comment: @snowman I think I see where your confusion is. You do not need $M$ to be the maximum of $|f(z)|$ over $\Gamma_R$, but you do need $M$ to be an upper bound for $|f(z)|$ over $\Gamma_R$.

Comment: OK, how come you didn't write what ML is? I get kinda confused when the O and o notations come in. I haven't looked at that stuff in ages. would it just be $$|\int f(z)dz|\leq ML=\frac{\pi R}{R^4+1}$$ ??? then we can see the RHS coverges to 0

Comment: @snowman $M = \frac{2}{R^4}$ and $L = \pi R$, so $ML = \frac{2\pi}{R^3}$.

Comment: sorry can you explain how you got to the fourth expression from the third expression on the second line please

Comment: @snowman by the triangle inequality, $$|z^4 + 1| \ge |z^4| - 1 = |z|^4 - 1 = R^4 - 1.$$ Since $R^4 > 2$, $(1/2)R^4 > 1$, so $R^4 - 1 > R^4 - (1/2)R^4 = (1/2)R^4$. Therefore $$\frac{1}{|z^4 + 1|} \le \frac{1}{R^4 - 1} \le \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}R^4} = \frac{2}{R^4}.$$